# Azure Wildcard certificate usage across multiple App services with different subdomains

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, subdomain

I have a web app that is hosted on three app services within a single subscription. All of them are hosted with different subdomains:

1. mystie.com
2. dev.mystie.com
3. demo.mystie.com

I bought Azure Wildcard certificate to provide ssl connection and I'm able to bind it to mystie.com and to dev.mystie.com, but not to demo.mystie.com.
It is listed in the Private Key Certificates table

[image]

But not in Private Certificate Thumbprint list on the TLS/SSL binding window

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S. Do I need to provide some additional information for you guys to help you figure out this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of hours, the certificate appeared on the list... can't explain this...